# Swift TableView Insert new row

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a TableView which take data from core data.

At the moment after the data are saved they will be inserted as first row.

here's the code i'm using to save the data (i'm not using the fetch controller because i'm not fetching any data but just loading them, this is because the date i'm loading are coming from a one to many relationship)

```
swimToConnect.addToMaterialsLocal(materialLocal)
    ad.saveContext()

        // Adding the new row to update the tableView
        let MyMaterialsVC = self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController as! MyMaterialsVC
        MyMaterialsVC.myMaterials.insert(materialLocal, at: 0)
        MyMaterialsVC.tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath], with: .none)
        MyMaterialsVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So i was wondering if there is a way to insert the row ordered by date.
I have them ordered by date like so:

```
var swim: SwimminPool! {
    didSet {
        myMaterials = (swim.materialsLocal?.allObjects as! [MaterialLocal]).sorted(by: {$0.createdAtLocal! > $1.createdAtLocal!})
    }
}
```

where created at is a date added by the user with a date picker.
when i save the new data obviously they are displayed at the first row, but if i dismiss the controller and then get back in then the data are displayed according to the date order.

is there a way to order the data in the correct order immediately after I have saved them?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you reload the table view just after adding the data. as i understood when you are loading the view, the table view is showing the data as ordered by date. so rather than inserting the row in the table view, just save the data in core data and reload the table view after that

Comment: You mean to remove these two lines:  MyMaterialsVC.myMaterials.insert(materialLocal, at: 0)
        MyMaterialsVC.tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath], with: .none)

Comment: when you are saving it in the core data and applying the sorting, right after that you can reload the data in your table view whose datasource is your core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this to following

```
swimToConnect.addToMaterialsLocal(materialLocal)
    ad.saveContext()

        // Adding the new row to update the tableView
        let MyMaterialsVC = self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController as! MyMaterialsVC
        MyMaterialsVC.myMaterials.insert(materialLocal, at: 0)
        MyMaterialsVC.myMaterials = (swim.materialsLocal?.allObjects as! [MaterialLocal]).sorted(by: {$0.createdAtLocal! > $1.createdAtLocal!})
        MyMaterialsVC.tableView.reloadData()
        MyMaterialsVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: it still shows the item as first when dismissing after saving... and then in the correct position if i exit and go back to the tableview

Comment: glad it helped @Marco

Answer (score 0):

The best way for this problem and the most efficient one is to use `NSFetchedResultsController`. It takes care of inserting and deleting items efficiently and it sorts them using `NSPredicate`.
You can create a Master Detail Application Template in Xcode and check the box for core data then Xcode creates a sample app with FetchedResultsController , there you can see how it works.

Comment: i'm new to swift so i'm still practicing... i use the fetcheresult controller to get the main entity...but i wouldn't know how to use it when getting the one to many entity..

Comment: You create an instance of `FetchedResultController` and you set an entity for it. It can show only one entity. Normally you show a single entity as your table view rows.If you want to get relationship values you ask `frc` to give you the entity and use the dot nation like (`myBook.author`) to get it's relationship.It works like an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of `RandomAccessCollection` which returns the insertion index in a sorted collection for a new item in a very efficient way. The benefit is you don't need to reload the entire table view.

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {
    func insertionIndex(for predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Index {
        var slice : SubSequence = self[...]

        while !slice.isEmpty {
            let middle = slice.index(slice.startIndex, offsetBy: slice.count / 2)
            if predicate(slice[middle]) {
                slice = slice[index(after: middle)...]
            } else {
                slice = slice[..<middle]
            }
        }
        return slice.startIndex
    }
}
```

And you can use it:

```
let insertionIndex = MyMaterialsVC.myMaterials.insertionIndex(for: { $0.createdAtLocal! < materialLocal.createdAtLocal!})
MyMaterialsVC.myMaterials.insert(materialLocal, at: insertionIndex)
MyMaterialsVC.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: insertionIndex, section: 0)], with: .none)
MyMaterialsVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```